# Voted vs. unvoted answer ratio?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, profile-page

I think it could be a good idea to have the ratio of your answers with 0 votes vs. your answers with 1+ votes on the profile page.

It could give further insight into the quality of a persons answers.

I'm generally thinking of this because I see quite a solid amount of people with relatively high reputation who have 1000 answers with 0 votes (I'm just making the numbers up of course ...) and 100 answers with 10+ votes.

I'm not saying this is bad, I'm just saying that if we can see the 'answer ratio' we can maybe make a slightly better distinction between people that just answer everything to try and 'grind reputation' and people that actually put time and thought into their answers.

This could however lead to people being afraid to answer questions because they might loose ratio...

Thoughts ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27261/what-is-a-good-question-answer-ratio but I still think this is relevant

Comment: Trivial answers to popular questions usually get many votes, and answers to less popular questions get few votes if any. So this rate tells mainly about how many unpopular/specialized questions you answer. So it'd discourage people from answering unpopular questions which are exactly the questions where answers are most needed.

Comment: @CodeInChaos ... agreed, will think about this :) would you mind posting this comment as an answer so we can discuss it easier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trivial answers to popular questions usually get many votes, and answers to less popular questions get few votes if any.

So this rate tells mainly about how many unpopular/specialized questions you answer. So it'd discourage people from answering unpopular questions which are exactly the questions where answers are most needed.

In my experience one of the fastest ways to get reputation is quickly answering a popular but easy question in a tag like C#. You usually get 5-10 upvoted for that if you're fast enough. And that for a simple look at this function + link to MSDN.

On the other hand when I answer a specialized question I usually get close to no upvotes. And that answer was certainly worth more since there are not 5+ people with a near identical answer.

Comment: As I can type fast enough for the quick answers, this problem is making me question how many answers it is worth posting.

Comment: although I completely agree with this, I still think that even in a very specific question if your answer gets at least 1 vote or is accepted with 0 votes, this could still increase ratio. When I ask a very specific question for example I tend to vote up any answer which is good and I think in a greater percentage of the cases a good answer gets at least 1 vote.

Comment: the ratio would also not be dependent on how much votes your answer has, rather just if it has any votes at all or is accepted .... or even maybe not negative ... however as a put more and more thought into this I really think you're right and this would have a negative effect rather than a positive one ... I'll think a bit more though

Answer (score 3):

If you look at this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/st/1140/zero-vote-ratio-for-top-100-and-bottom-100-over-1000) you'll see the following

**Top 100**

- Lowest Ratio: .5%
- Highest Ratio: 38.9%
- Mean Average : 18%

**Bottom 100 above 10000**

- Lowest Ratio: 8.9%
- Highest Ratio: 49%
- Mean Average : 27.4%

**Bottom 100 above 1000**

- Lowest Ratio: 0%
- Highest Ratio: 100%
- Mean Average : 40%

So there's a trend that as you go up in reputation you can expect to see a lower variance of ratio of Zero vote answers as well lower average.

This isn't very surprising or interesting since in my experience, the more questions you answer the better you are at 1) identifying which questions will yield answers that get up-voted 2) how to provide questions that get up voted.

So as per the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you. Reputation is never given, it is earned by convincing fellow users that you know what you’re talking about.

I think the above data demonstrates that at best the Zero answer metric would provide a rougher not a more precise measurement.

Comment: +1, a good metric either is not subjective to or finds a way to mitigate the problem of small sample size.

Comment: this is what I mean by good answers you put time into :) this should definitely increase your ratio :D

Comment: although the best answers are not those with the most time put into them of course ....

Answer (score 1):

As well as not answering they could always delete answers with 0 votes after some time has passed, which will increase their ratio. I don't really think that it would be a reliable, or even very good indicator of answer quality.

Comment: depends on the idea, deleting 0/negative rated answer should not increase ratio, also a time buffer could be set so you can't cheat like that, ratio can also be calculated on weekly/monthly basis rather than instantly like rating

Comment: It will definitely not be reliable, I will argue however that rating is also not completely reliable. The question is will it be beneficial ?

Comment: I don't think that it would provide any substancial benefit, but you are right about rep.

Comment: It would provide benefit IMHO (at least to me :D). So if you have to say yes or no, do you prefer having it or not ?

Comment: After reading @CodeInChaos's answer I'm going to say no